# What is special about chatroom events?

Tags: support, chat

I saw that a chatroom event is going to be held. What is special about chatroom events? Aren't they just the same as the usual chatting? I went to the FAQ and the Help Center, but I see no useful information there.

Comment: Chat room events are just pre-scheduled times when an alert goes out that an event is starting and then people do some specific thing. For example the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room holds events for different kinds of scheduled [targeted closing sessions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers?tab=schedule).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chatroom events are just easy ways for moderators of a room to communicate a scheduled function.  They can be created with any purpose in mind, much like their real life counterparts.

In the StackOverflow Python chat, we typically schedule our [room meetings as events](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python?tab=schedule) so that everyone is reminded of the occurrence outside of having pinned messages in the starred/pinned messages area of the interface.

Finally, the StackOverflow dev team was nice enough to make the events exportable, meaning it's easy to get "official" reminders in whatever calendar solution the user chooses.

Answer (score 8):

They're just like real-life meetings, which are ultimately just people talking as they usually would. The difference is that the people are talking about something specific, in a pre-determined place, at a pre-determined time. If you didn't do that, you would not be able to guarantee that all interested parties were present at the same time in the same place, and your event wouldn't be very successful.